# Raspberries together or apart?

Tags: planting, raspberries

I bought some raspberry plants today. These were stocks in a dirt pot. The instructions say to soak and then plant 3 feet apart.

Each container came with 2 separate stocks/roots -- should I plant these together or each individual stock 3 feet a part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are two completely separate plants (not two stems growing from one bunch of roots) I would plant them separately.

They may look a bit "sparse" this year, but next year you should have several canes (British for "stocks" I assume) from each plant.

FWIW in the UK you would normally plant the canes when they were dormant (November to March) - but maybe your "winter" lasts a bit longer than ours.

Comment: I ended up planting separately. They were separate canes/roots/etc. It's a bit late to plant, but we just moved into this brand new property.